# Read html file after making a .jar file

Tags: java, html, eclipse, filereader

I'm working on a application, but when i try to run it as a .jar file i have some problems with reading a html file, who is in my src folder. Note that there is no problem doing this while i'm running this in eclipse.

code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/Text/testText.html"));
```

Normally this works fine, but after creating a .jar and running it, it gives me the following error: No such file or directory.

Does someone know what I do wrong?

Comment: First make sure your html file is being packaged as part of your jar.  Since a jar is just a .zip file you should be able to open it and see. But if t is follow the link in my close vote.

Comment: I can see it when im opening my jar like a zip file. Tried this:  InputStream inS = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Text/testText.html"); 
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inS));     Still nothing changes

Comment: Solved it!  Did: InputStream inS = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Text/testText.html");   Thanks for the fast reply!\